# Satellite image of agriculture land cover for North Korea

Tags: geospatial, agriculture, korea

I am looking for free satellite images of agriculture land cover for North Korea.

Is it available on [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), which image should I download?

I'm looking for imagery with which I can do an analysis (in ArcGIS) of how much vegetation is healthy on the agriculture land and how much is lost due to drought.

Comment: Specific what satellite imagery are you looking for ? Like Landsat ? sentinel ? There are many different kinds of them...

Comment: @PROBERT, nothing specific. I'm looking for an imagery, using which I can do an analysis (in ArcGIS) of how much vegetation is healthy on the agriculture land and how much is lost due to drought.

Answer (score 3):

https://libra.developmentseed.org/

https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/viewer.html

http://glcf.umd.edu/

https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/

It's like I said maybe your best bet is to contact the universities in South Korea and find out. I am sure they have somebody there can lead you to find the information you need for North Korea datasets.

Answer (score 2):

In [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), on the 'Data Sets' tab, expand the menu for 'Landsat Archive', then 'Collection 1 Level-1' to get Landsat 8 (expand 'Landsat Legacy' for older Landsat). You can then generate NDVI or whatever other analysis you wish in ArcGIS. Also available on Earth Explorer is 'Vegetation Monitoring' which has NDVI of MODIS and a few others. If you don't know what NDVI is or know the difference between MODIS and Landsat, I would recommend studying up on the a bit more before you run any kind of analysis as there is a lot of room for incorrect interpretation.

Here is a coverage map of MODIS NDVI:
[image]